# binary search tree_ how to update and calculate the imbalance_python

Tags: tree, binary, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, imbalanced-data

I am building a binary search tree, and I want to update the imbalance when I add a child and use this function in the add_child function.

But now I have met some problem, can someone tell me where is wrong? Thank you very much!

And it is correct to use it in the add_child function, if add_child, self.imbalance()

```
def update_imbalance(self) -> int:

self.imbalance += abs(self.right_child.value-self.left_child.value)
```

**the error:
def update_imbalance(self) -> int:

> ```
>   self.imbalance += abs(self.right_child.value-self.left_child.value)
> ```

E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
Node.py:51: AttributeError**

Comment: The error says it all. You are accessing a `value` attribute on something that is `None`. So... check first that this is not the case.

Comment: Maybe you could format your code